# SQL Server - calcular quantidade ocorrências de palavra em uma coluna, por registro

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Meu objetivo é criar um select para retornar o total de ocorrências de uma palavra, de uma coluna, por registro

Minha tabela está modelada da seguinte forma:
id  /  nome_arquivo / qntd_pg  /  conteudo

ex: Quero buscar quantas vezes a palavra 'Rio' aparece na coluna [conteudo], para cada registro do banco.

O código abaixo não dá nenhum erro, mas retorna a quantidade como Null. É a primeira vez que estou usando a estrutura if no Sql Server.

**Segue o Código:**

```
declare @palavra varchar(30),
        @cont int,
        @result int
select
    [DCM_conteudo]  
FROM [dcm_digital].[dbo].[conteudo_dcm] 
where upper([DCM_conteudo]) like '%Rio%' and [DCM_id] = 1
    if  @palavra = 'Rio' 
    begin
        select @result = count(@cont);
    end;    
    select @result;
```

---

**Atualizando...**

Solução no post: [SQL Server - Retornar apenas a palavra buscada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434803/sql-server-retornar-apenas-a-palavra-buscada/435487#435487)

Answer (score 1):

Renata, realizei uns ajustes para utilizar localmente. Você precisará alterar a tabela utilizada, mas isso é simples.
Você pode utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @conteudo_dcm TABLE (DCM_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DCM_conteudo VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('Rio e a RIO vai se repetir então teremos 2 :D')
INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('um Rio apenas... então teremos 1 :D')
INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('tres pra este caso. Rio, Rio, Rio XD.. então 3.. blz?')

declare @palavra varchar(30) = 'Rio',
        @cont int,
        @result int,
        @palavraLike varchar(30) = '%Rio%'
SELECT
    [DCM_conteudo],
    (LEN([DCM_conteudo]) - LEN(REPLACE([DCM_conteudo], @palavra, ''))) /
            LEN(@palavra)
FROM @conteudo_dcm
where upper([DCM_conteudo]) like @palavraLike-- and [DCM_id] = 1
```

Nesse caso estou contando conforme localizo a palavra na string para cada linha.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, mas ainda estou com um impasse. Seu cód. retorna não apenas as palavras buscadas, mas tb palavras que tenham essa palavra em sua composição. Ex: a palavra é Rio, mas tb encontra a palavra salário.

Comment: Bem observado! No link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it acredito que conseguimos fazer o que pretende. Nesse caso precisará usar o Full-text index e utilizar a função CONTAINS ou FREETEXT conforme exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente caso desejar contar apenas a quantidade de registros que possuem alguma vez a palavra 'Rio', ou seja, quando houver 2 vezes na minha row irá contabilizar somente uma:

```
declare @palavra varchar(30),
        @result int

select
    @result = Count([DCM_conteudo]) -- Set a variavel Result com a quantidade de registros retornados
    FROM [dcm_digital].[dbo].[conteudo_dcm] 
    where upper([DCM_conteudo]) like '%'+@palavra+'%' -- se necessario and [DCM_id] = 1

select @result; -- Apresenta o resultado
```

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, Marcos, mas acredito que essa implementação não seja a cabível para a questão já que contabiliza o todo e não a específica do registro. De qualquer forma tenho certeza que ajudará alguém com uma dúvida semelhante. Abraços.