# SQL Server - Retornar apenas a palavra buscada

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou com um problema onde o cód. abaixo retorna não apenas as palavras buscadas, mas tb palavras que tenham essa palavra em sua composição.

**Ex:** O termo é Rio, mas tb encontra termos como salário.

No link abaixo, é possível ver minha 1ª pergunta sobre o assunto. 
[SQL Server - calcular quantidade ocorrências de palavra em uma coluna, por registro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427182/sql-server-calcular-quantidade-ocorr%c3%aancias-de-palavra-em-uma-coluna-por-regis][1])

```
DECLARE @conteudo_dcm TABLE (DCM_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DCM_conteudo VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('Rio e a RIO vai se repetir então teremos 2 :D')
INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('um Rio apenas... então teremos 1 salario :D')
INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('tres pra este caso. Rio, Rio, Rio XD.. então 3.. blz?')

declare @palavra varchar(30) = 'Rio',
        @cont int,
        @result int,
        @palavraLike varchar(30) = '%Rio%'
SELECT
    [DCM_conteudo],
    (LEN([DCM_conteudo]) - LEN(REPLACE([DCM_conteudo], @palavra, ''))) /
            LEN(@palavra)
FROM @conteudo_dcm
where upper([DCM_conteudo]) like @palavraLike-- and [DCM_id] = 1
```

Comment: Me parece que o que você necessita é: 1) se for o início do campo então 'rio '; 2) se for o final do campo então ' rio' e se for no meio do campo então ' rio '. Pode ser que o caractere ' ' seja substituído por alguma caractere de pontuação. Não sei se no SQL-Server é possível utilizar expressões regulares que certamente facilitariam sua vida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que conta as ocorrências da palavra que você deseja:

```
CREATE FUNCTION contar_ocorrencias(@palavra VARCHAR(30),
                                   @frase   VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE @inteiro INTEGER;
  DECLARE @inicio  INTEGER;
  DECLARE @meio    INTEGER;
  DECLARE @fim     INTEGER;
  DECLARE @tamanho INTEGER;
  DECLARE @total   INTEGER;
  DECLARE @posicao INTEGER;

  SET @tamanho = LEN(REPLACE(@palavra, ' ', '.'));
  SET @total   = LEN(REPLACE(@frase, ' ', '.'));

  WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @copia   VARCHAR(100);

    SET @copia = @frase;
    SET @inteiro = PATINDEX(@palavra, @frase);

    if @inteiro > 0
    BEGIN
      RETURN 1;
    END;

    SET @inicio  = PATINDEX(@palavra + '[^a-zA-Z]%', @frase);

    IF @inicio > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @frase = SUBSTRING(@frase, @tamanho + 1, LEN(REPLACE(@frase, ' ', '.')) - @tamanho + 1);
    END;

    SET @meio    = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]' + @palavra + '[^a-zA-Z]%', @frase);

    IF @meio > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @frase = SUBSTRING(@frase, 1, @meio) + SUBSTRING(@frase, @meio + @tamanho + 1, LEN(REPLACE(@frase, ' ', '.')) - @meio + @tamanho);
    END;

    SET @fim     = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]' + @palavra, @frase);

    IF @fim > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @frase = SUBSTRING(@frase, @fim, LEN(REPLACE(@frase, ' ', '.')) - @tamanho + 1);
    END;

    IF @copia = @frase
    BEGIN
      BREAK;
    END;
  END;

  RETURN (@total - LEN(REPLACE(@frase, ' ', '.'))) / @tamanho;
END;
GO
```

E para utilizar:

```
DECLARE @conteudo_dcm TABLE (
  DCM_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  DCM_conteudo VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('Rio e a RIO vai se repetir então teremos 2 :D');
INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('um Rio apenas... então teremos 1 salario :D');
INSERT INTO @conteudo_dcm VALUES ('tres pra este caso. Rio, Rio, Rio XD.. então 3.. blz?');

SELECT DCM_conteudo,
       dbo.contar_ocorrencias('rio', DCM_conteudo)
  FROM @conteudo_dcm
```

Comment: Obrigada! Uma dica para quem estiver usando os campos do banco como nvarchar(max):  Alterar o tipo da variável @frase, e todas as variáveis que estiverem como "integer", alterar para "bigint" !